# Variable is empty when logged outside the block in which it is set

Tags: cypress, closures

```js
    let studentName: any = '';
    cy.get('app-screen').find('input[id="studentName"]').invoke('val').as('name')
    cy.get('@name').then((name) => {
      studentName = name;
      cy.log('Student Name: ' + studentName )
    })
    cy.log('Student Name: ' + studentName )
```

The code above prints the student name for the first log statement.

The log statement outside the then block is empty in test runner.

Any help as to why the value `studentName` is not printing outside then block? How do I get the value outside the `then` block?

Comment: Since Cypress is asynchronous it won't return values outside the loop  which you are expecting. But you can perform the operation you want to do inside the(). May I know why exactly you want students name outside then?

Comment: I have to use that student name value in successive tests as input. If I am unable to to use outside then block then I can't use in other tests.

Comment: Do not be afraid to use `.then()`, it is the corner stone of asynchronous programming. If you want to use `cy.get('@name')` across other tests, you must refresh it in a `beforeEach()`.

Answer (score 4):

What happens is the test runner runs through the test and adds the commands it finds to the [Cypress Command Queue](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#The-Cypress-Command-Queue).

When it adds the line `cy.log('Student Name: ' + studentName )`, it gets the value of studentName as it is ***before the command queue starts running***, i.e when `studentName = ''`.

But it only performs the `cy.log()` later when the queue gets to that command, giving the impression `studentName` has not been updated.

You can defer the reading of `studentName` until later with a `.then()` Anything inside a .then callback will execute only after preceding queue commands.

```js
let studentName: any = '';
cy.get('app-screen').find('input[id="studentName"]').invoke('val').as('name')
cy.get('@name').then((name) => {
  studentName = name;
  cy.log('Student Name: ' + studentName )
})

// Now get the updated studentName
cy.then(() => {
  cy.log('Student Name: ' + studentName )  // adds this to the queue after 
                                           // all previous commands have run
})
```

---

**Other options**

If `student` object is important in a lot of tests, consider creating it in a `beforeEach()` and using `function()` form of the test

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.get('app-screen')
    .find('input[id="studentName"]')
    .invoke('val')
    .as('name')
})

it('tests the student', function() {  // NOTE function not arrow function
  
  expect(this.name).to.eq('Saran')    // access with "this" prefix

})

it('also tests the student', function() {  // NOTE function not arrow function
  
  cy.log("Student: ' + this.name)    // still has value

})
```

---

**Script1.js**

```js
cy.fixture('studentData.json').then(studentData => {

  cy.get('app-screen')
    .find('input[id="studentName"]')
    .invoke('val')
    .then(name => {
      studentData.name = name
      cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/studentData.json', studentData)
    })
})
```

**Script2.js**

```js
import studentData from 'cypress/fixtures/studentData.json'

// Don't use cy.fixture('studentData.json') here 
// because the fixture command caches the data
// so update will not always be seen
```

Comment: The student name gets printed within the 2nd then block. But, it doesn't get printed outside the 2nd then block. I have to use this student name value in many tests. If I can't take that value outside the 2nd then block, then we have the same issue again. Is there any other option available, please...

Comment: That's expected behaviour with asynchronous code (nearly all Cypress commands are asynchronous). The answer to "is there any other option" is - it depends on the shape of the tests.

Comment: The Script1.ts file has the test written. This test will have a method 'getStudentName' called which has the above code I mentioned to get the student name. This method is available in Script2.ts. I cannot bring this code to the test in Script1.ts as we need to call this method in Script2.ts at various points during execution. I am not sure I can implement in before each loop as the 'getStudentName' method has to remain in Script2.ts file. I have to use this method only to get the student name. Please help.

Comment: I saw the other question with Script1, Script2, Script3 but it was confusing for me. To share data across across spec files, there are a couple of options. 1) Write data to a fixture file and read it in the other specs. 2) Put `beforeEach()` in `/support/index.js` then it will run across all specs.