# Use a variable outside of a function in Cypress

Tags: javascript, function, testing, cypress

I want to use a value that i got from a website and stored in a variable outside of a "within" function to comapre it with another value.

```
cy.get('.TableCloumn_3')
    .within($tr => {
     cy.get('[class="ng-star-inserted"]').then(($span) => {

    const relRep = $span.text();
   
     cy.log(relRep);
      })
    })
    
  
   cy.log(relRep) 
    
  })
```

The first cy.log for relRep prints me the value but the second one does not. When I change from it from cont to var it also gives me an empty log. How can i use this value outside the function?

Comment: Duplicate of [Value stored in then block is empty when printed or used outside the block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71088483/16997707)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a variable at the top level and assign it inside the function

```js
let foo

function bar() {
  foo = "1"
}
bar()
console.log(foo)
```