# How can I access the variable declared inside then function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, cypress

I want to access the input value given/already present in the input field. I am trying the below solution but I can't access it outside the then function.

```
    let name
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.get('[id=username]').type("Kanye")
    cy.get('[id=username]').then((input) => {
      name = input.val()
      cy.log(name)  //Works here
    })
    cy.log(name)    //Does not work here
```

Can you help me modify this function? Or suggest me any alternative I can use.

Comment: `then` implies it's asynchronous.  So likely the `then` hasn't executed when you try to log name.  That's why there is a `then` - so you can put your code that needs to wait for the async part in there.

Comment: This is my explanation of the multiple issues that arise from this code [Value stored in then block is empty when printed or used outside the block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71088483/16997707)